# Can Dataset filtering be done from outside the dataset?

Tags: delphi, dataset, filtering

I have two TDBLookupComboBox controls that I'd like to connect to the same dataset, but have each one display a different subset of the data. If I only needed one box, I'd use filtering on the dataset, but I need to be able to display both of them at the same time, and I'm not aware of any way to do that.  Does anyone know if it can be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using a TClientDataSet, you can clone the cursor (TClientDataSet.CloneCursor) into another TClientDataSet that doesn't have the ProviderName property set. Both ClientDataSet now point to the same data in memory but can have their own filters.